# Best practices for REST API that access multiple environments

Tags: rest, convention

When writing a RESTful API that needs to access different environments such as a lab/test database and a production database, what's the best practices around setting up the API?

Should there be a `@PathParam`?:

```
/employee/{emp_id}/{environment}
/{environment}/employee/{emp_id}/
```

Should there be a `@QueryParam`?:

```
/employee/{emp_id}/?environment="test"
/employee/{emp_id}/?environment="prod"
```

Should there be a field in the payload?:

```
{"emp_id":"123","environment":"test"}
{"emp_id":"123","environment":"production"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact I see two ways to handle this. The reason to use one or the other corresponds to what is the most convenient to implement in your RESTful application.

- **Using a path parameter**

  With this approach, it should be a path parameter at the very beginning of the resource path. So URL would be like this: `/{environment}/employee/{emp_id}`. Such approach is convenient if you have several applications deployed under different root paths. For example:

  `/test`: application packaged with the configuration for the test environment
  `/prod`: application packaged with the configuration for the production

  In this case, applications for each environment are isolated.
- **Using a custom header**

  You could also a custom header to specify on which environment to route. Github uses something like that to select the version of the API to use. See this link: https://developer.github.com/v3/#current-version. It's not exactly the same thing but you could have something like that:

  ```
  GET /employee/{emp_id}
  x-env: test
  ```

  A reverse proxy could handle this header and route the request to the right environment.

I'm not convinced by the approach within the payload since an field `environment` isn't actually a part of the representation for element resource `employee`. Regarding the query parameter approach, it's similar since such parameters apply to the request on the resource.

Hope it helps you,

Comment: I was going to write something similar, but @thierry beat me to it, so I will upvote Thierry's. However, I would not go the path route. Path routes can make sense when dealing with versions (though there is much debate if it should be part of the path or a header), as it identifies the resource within a context. But when dealing with particular environments, I would suggest using a header. The ideal, really is to have a different host URL entirely, so you cannot ever risk messing it up, but if you are stuck, go for the header.

Comment: Thanks very much, Avi! I definitively agree you ;-) We must be very careful to separate such environments. Different host URLs would be even better than an header ;-)

Comment: I spent a whole bunch of years doing IT in financial services. Admins and devs screwing up and either typing into the wrong window or sending the wrong parameter and thus accidentally deleting a production ID or executing a trade or running an analysis on prod instead of dev was all-too-commong and painful. Anything that separates more is good in my book! :-)

Comment: I see exactly what you mean ;-)